# Is there a formalism for the kinds of constraints we can implement with indexed-views? Or at least a rule-of-thumb?

Tags: sql-server, relational-theory, materialized-view, database-theory

SQL Server’s Indexed Views provide a performant way to implement *certain classes* of database-scoped constraints - [such as ensuring a value is unique over multiple tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12781/10044) - or other [non-key, cross-table value constraints](https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/).

As far as I understand it: provided you can reduce your desired constraint to a single `SELECT` query using some combination of `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, and/or `COUNT_BIG`/`SUM` such that invalid data causes duplicate output rows then using an indexed-view is doable.

…but how can I know (or ideally: prove) that some proposed constraint can be implemented this way? And how can I know that some other kind of constraint is impossible to implement?

Another consideration is that the limitation of only having `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` becomes less of a restriction with the help of utility-tables containing data-ranges (either manually maintained or using `GENERATE_SERIES`) - this enables other classes of constraints to be implemented - but I struggle to conceptualise those classes (do they have names?)

Comment: On the helper table with two rows my answer here predates that blog post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445586/73226

Comment: Nothing formal, but it needs to be simple to identify the view rows affected by a change to any table row.